# Displaying sidebar items according to user role

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, acl

I want to display the sidebar items of `vx-sidebar` according to user role. I'm using acl plugin. There are two users admin and editor. Both have different sidebar items. I have set the roles  and everything.But everytime user login, the sidebar items doesn't render initially, I have to refresh the page then the sidebar items render according to role. I am using firebase firestore. And i am setting the initial role as the user.uid found in two different collections of admin and editor.

I have also set the user role in the local storage and vuex.store, but still the elements don't render on initial login.Please help me with this. I have spend days with solving this. But doesn't find solution

acl.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { AclInstaller, AclCreate, AclRule } from 'vue-acl'
import router from '@/router'

Vue.use(AclInstaller)



let initialRole = localStorage.getItem('userRole')
console.log(initialRole)
export default new AclCreate({
  initial: initialRole,
  notfound: '/pages/not-authorized',
  router,
  acceptLocalRules: true,
  globalRules: {
    admin: new AclRule('admin').generate(),
    editor: new AclRule('editor').generate(),


  }
})
```

VxSidebarItem.vue

```
    <div :class="[{'vs-sidebar-item-active':activeLink}, {'disabled-item pointer-events-none': isDisabled}]" class="vs-sidebar--item" v-if="canSee">


   computed: {
        canSee() {
            this.$acl.check(localStorage.getItem('userRole'));
             console.log(localStorage.getItem('userRole'))
            if(this.to) {
                return this.$acl.check(this.$router.match(this.to).meta.rule)
            }
            return true
        }
    },
```

router.js

```
 {
                    path: '/',
                    redirect: '/dashboard/jobs'
                },
                {
                    path: '/dashboard/jobs',
                    name: 'Jobs',
                    component: () => import('./views/tpo/Jobs.vue'),
                    meta: {

                        rule:'admin',

                    }
                },
```